# Android: Not able to see internal storage when choosing file(Random device)

Tags: android, android-intent, storage, scoped-storage

While picking a document from the File Explorer, I am not able to see **Internal storage** in a few devices. It's just showing "Recent", "Downloads" and "Images" tab when File Explorer opens.
The thing is this issue occurs in a few devices.

Here is the code I have used to pick a document from a File Explorer:

```
val intentPickDocument = Intent()
intentPickDocument.action = Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT
intentPickDocument.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
intentPickDocument.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true)
intentPickDocument.type = "*/*"
val extraMimeTypes = arrayOf(
    Constant.IMAGE_PNG,
    Constant.IMAGE_JPEG,
    Constant.IMAGE_JPG,
    Constant.DOC_PDF
)
intentPickDocument.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, extraMimeTypes)
startActivityForResult(
    intentPickDocument,
    Constant.REQUEST_CODE_DOC_PICKER
)
```

Here,

```
const val IMAGE_PNG = "image/png"
const val IMAGE_JPEG = "image/jpeg"
const val IMAGE_JPG = "image/jpg"
const val DOC_PDF = "application/pdf"
```

I tried in Samsung J7 Nxt(Android 9) devices and OnePlus 7 Pro(Android 10) and it's working fine for me.

The device in which I am facing this issue:
OnePlus 7 - Android 10

I also checked in other OnePlus 7 device and it's working fine in that.

What might be the cause?

[image]

Comment: That's normal. Click on the "..." button in the action bar (with the drawer closed) and you should see a checkbox to enable viewing "Internal Storage" (which is really [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) from the SDK's standpoint).